# Using lxml to query a website in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, lxml

I am currently trying to query the following website ([HPBD](https://kxp.k10plus.de/DB=1.77/DB=1.77/LNG=EN/)) using `lxml` in Python 3. I need to scrape some information from each search result. For now, I have obtained a list of titles I would like to search (approx. 100). I here append the first five as an example:

```
for book in BOOK_TITLES:
    print('-', book, '\n')


- Apologie des ministres du culte, qui ont prêté la déclaration exigée par la loi du 7 vendém. an 4. contre les critiques de mm. Dédoyar & Vanhoren, les Motifs de Malines & autres brochures 

- Observations sur la déclaration exigée des ministres des cultes, en vertu de la loi du 7 vendémiaire, an 4 

- l'Eloquence chrétienne dans l'idée et dans la pratique 

- Verscheyde leeringen en exempelen der oude vaders 

- Godtvruchtige leeringen en gebeden voor de eerste communie
```

However, I am quite new to web scraping and started by playing around with BeatifulSoup to see if the idea was right, but could not get anything out of it (see code below).

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import time
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS


for book in BOOK_TITLES:
    text = requests.get('https://kxp.k10plus.de/DB=1.77/SET=5/TTL=1/CMD?MATCFILTER=N&MATCSET=N&ACT0=&ACT=SRCHA&IKT=1016&SRT=YOP&ADI_IKT9200=&TRM=' + urllib.parse.quote(book)).text
    soup = BS(text)
    print(soup)
```

The problem is that the 'mutable' part of the URL for, e.g., title 3 in the list above is:

```
l%27Eloquence+chrétienne+dans+l%27idée+et+dans+la+pratique
```

While `urllib.parse.quote(book)` returns:

```
l%27Eloquence%20chr%C3%A9tienne%20dans%20l%27id%C3%A9e%20et%20dans%20la%20pratique
```

I am using Google Chrome and Python 3. Any fix for the above code and suggestions for alternatives using `lxml` are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode, quote_plus

payload = {"TRM":"l'Eloquence chrétienne dans l'idée et dans la pratique"}
result = urlencode(payload, quote_via=quote_plus)
# 'TRM=l%27Eloquence+chrétienne+dans+l%27idée+et+dans+la+pratique'
```

Comment: The code worked. I would be happy to mark it as a definitive answer if you could add an lxml equivalent (a short piece of code that would substitute the BeatifulSoup loop in the question)